# What's a truly "Angularesque" way to implement maxlength on a textarea field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm writing a directive to enforce maxlength on a textarea field (HTML version < 5). I'm using AngularJS. As such, I want to get it done in a correct AngularJS manner. However, when I do it "Angularesque" as I perceive it, I can't quite get it to work completely.

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []);
myAppModule.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.textareaText = "";
});

myAppModule.directive('myMaxlength', ['$compile', '$log', function($compile, $log) {
    return {
        priority: 10000,
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        compile: function (elem, attrs) {
            elem.attr("ng-trim", "false");
            return function(scope, linkElem, linkAttrs, ctrl) {
                var maxlength = parseInt(linkAttrs.myMaxlength, 10);
                ctrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                    $log.info("In parser function value = [" + value + "].");
                    if (value.length > maxlength)
                    {
                        $log.info("The value [" + value + "] is too long!");
                        value = value.substr(0, maxlength);
                        ctrl.$setViewValue(value);
                        ctrl.$render();
                        $log.info("The value is now truncated as [" + value + "].");
                    }
                    return value;
                });
            };
        }
    };
}]);
})();
```

This nearly works (see the **JSFIDDLE** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ksevksev/J7MJF/) Note: This fiddle has since been updated with the chosen solution below, but the code above still exhibits the problem noted here.). It correctly limits characters going to the model, and renders that back to the display. However, you can continue to enter spaces to exceed the specified maxlength. The extra spaces don't get into the model, but they clutter the display. I believe this has something to do with ng-trim. As you can see (in the code snippet) I'm setting the attribute in the compile function, but it's too late by then. Some suggest manually calling compile within your compile function to force AngularJS to recognize the dynamically-added attribute, but that "appears" to create another copy and doesn't fix the display problem. Putting `ng-trim="false"` on the textarea element works, but I want a clean solution where all the user needs to do is add one attribute specifying the max length.

Here is another example (see the **JSFIDDLE** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ksevksev/czMJS/)) that is not quite as "Angularesque" in my opinion but get's the job done.

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []);
myAppModule.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.textareaText = true;
});
myAppModule.directive('myMaxlength', ['$log', function($log) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            var maxlength = parseInt(attrs.myMaxlength, 10);
            $log.info("maxlength=[" + maxlength + "]");
            elem.bind('keydown', function (event) {
                $log.info("elem.val().length=[" + elem.val().length + "]");

                if (elem.val().length >= maxlength)
                {
                    // Void event Except backspace
                    if (event.keyCode != 8){
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]); 
})();
```

So, what's a truly "Angularesque" way to implement maxlength on a textarea field? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - No problem. Thanks for taking a look. I'm not trying to create words here, but thought that Angularesque would give the reader an accurate idea of what I'm after.

Comment: It does, very succinct. :-)

Comment: Not angularesque but, have you tried HTML5's textarea `maxlength` attribute? It seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - Thanks, but I must support older browsers and hence can't count on HTML5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `$attr.$set()` (see [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$set)) to add the `ng-trim` attribute in a way that `ngModel` would recognize.

Change this line of your code in the compile function:

```
elem.attr("ng-trim", "false");
```

to this:

```
attrs.$set("ngTrim", "false");
```

**Note**: Remember to change the attribute value to **camelCase**!

You can also do it in a link function (no need for the compile function):

```
linkAttrs.$set("ngTrim", "false");
```

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/J7MJF/7/

Answer (score 3):

You can use ngMaxlength argument on an input field in your html file (documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input)

For example

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myRestrictedText" ng-maxlength="10"/>
```

Comment: But...the question is about `textarea`, not `input`. It's right there in the title. And the fiddle.

Comment: @emiidee Thanks for that but I looked at that already. It's helpful in some situations where you want validation only. However, I'm looking to also restrict the input before it becomes invalid. (See http://jsfiddle.net/ksevksev/YWq7g/). Thanks!

Comment: The native html maxlength attribute makes it so that you cannot input any text after the max is hit: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @emiidee Thanks again, but I'm dealing with a textarea element (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp). Also, I must support older browsers so the new HTML5 maxlength attribute for textarea doesn't get me where I need to go.